# Why is Eclipse 2022-12 (4.26.0) Not Consistently Providing the Ability to Format XML?

Tags: xml, eclipse

I have two XML files that are part of the same Eclipse project.  When editing one of them, Eclispe provides the ability to format the XML:

[image]

But when editing the second XML file, this ability is missing:

[image]

This second XML file is 135 lines and 56k in size.

Why is Eclipse not presenting Format in the Source menu for this second XML file?

**Update**

Eclipse is presenting two Source menu items.  One has the Format sub-menu item and the other doesn't (not shown):

[image]

Comment: You have opened the second file in the plain editor. Eclipse provides different editors for different things. You can right-click and choose _Open With_ to open the file with a different editor.

Comment: @howlger This is strange.  You are right, even though the file has a .XML extension.  What's really weird and what I may not have noticed before, is that Eclipse is presenting two Source menu items; one that does have Format and one that doesn't.  I'll update my post to show this.  In the meantime, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: In your case you have two different implementations of XML support: [WTP](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/) provides the XML Editor and [LemMinX](https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx) via [Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper). For the second XML support, you have to open the file with the _Generic Text Editor_, but you get some XML support even when opening in a different. This causes the two _Source_ menus. In your second screenshot right-click in the editor and choose _Source > Format_ (but this is a different XML formatter than the first one (WTP).